Setting maxConnections for TcpClient in reactor netty application
I am using reactor-netty library from Projectreactor to create an a TCP client application. I am using below simple code snippets which are provided at official docuemntation
When I run the app using same configuration it never creates more than 1 channel/socket even after increasing number of requests per second to 100.
I am very new to reactor-netty and wanted to check if I am missing anything here. Any help is appreciated, thanks
This is the code snippet I tried. obviously host and port are different.
import reactor.netty.Connection;
import reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider;
import reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionProvider provider =
                ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
                                  .maxConnections(50)
                                  .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) (1)
                                  .build();

        Connection connection =
                TcpClient.create(provider)
                         .host("example.com")
                         .port(80)
                         .connectNow();

        connection.onDispose()
                  .block();
    }
}


In the snippet above, you connect just once, so one connection in the pool. Why do you expect more?
